# How to make the select searchable with another options?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

In react-select we have the possibility to create searchable input select.

I have already by default created my searchable react-select input with a list of options (filteredUsers) which is made up of 2 users

I would like that when a user carries out a search, it no longer takes into account the 'filteredUsers' data but that the search is carried out on all users ('users')

I haven't found a way to be able to 'edit' this list of options once the search is done so that my user can search a larger list.

I have read through articles that react-select offers 'filterOption' in order to configure the filtering options, but I have difficulty seeing how I could put this in place.

I use "react-select": "^5.8.0",

This is my code at the moment :

```
 <ReactSelect
  className="basic-single"
  classNamePrefix="select"
  isSearchable={true}
  options={filteredUsers.map((user) => ({
   value: user.engineer,
   label: user.engineer,
  }))}
  onChange={(event) => {
   handleEngineerChange({
    event,
    el,
   key,
   filteredUsers,
    });
     }} 
 />
```

Comment: You can only search from the data you provided, the "filterOption" is used for ignoreCase, timing and other things but it will also filter from the provided data. You can build a custom select if you want to render and search from different data